# Are questions about trading software are on topic

Tags: discussion

I just wanted to ask whether it's the right place to ask about trading software?

**EDIT**: What I mean, are not just technical questions about how to use a specific software but question related to practical implications on trading while using certain applications.
Hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "trading software"?  Stock trading software like [QCharts](http://www.qcharts.com/) or Ameritrade's software?

Comment: I think such [questions](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/21644/7590) are acceptable if defined clearly enough, but in the case of the OP's question on the main site about algorithmic trading software, I'm not sure that's the case. The question I'm referring to seems to ask about writing custom algorithms in software, which any algorithmic trading platform would allow by definition, but based on the OP's comments, it seems like the question is really just "what are some algo-trading platforms" in which case it's a duplicate.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @EugeneS What do you mean, "practical implications on trading while using certain applications" ? Do you mean how using a software package will affect your returns, how the trading experience is different, how to use a *specific* software package, or something else? As it stands, your [current question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/21644/7590) still seems too vague to me since you don't ask about a *specific* software package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on what you are asking about the trading software.

Purely technical support type of questions are not welcome here.  Go the developer's site for that.

The other types of questions should be acceptable, within the scope of the site.